# Can we use HAproxy load balancer along with nginx acting as a server?

Tags: nginx, cloud, load-balancing, haproxy

In our project, we want to use HAproxy as a Load balancer which is done on a VM, and Nginx is used as a server. Is it possible to do? or is it necessary that we use one Nginx for the load balancer and another one as a server?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, HAProxy only need an address:port

So you can forward to an NGinx that will expose your app

Or forward directly to applications port

Both will work.

```
  HAProxy
  |      |
  |      |
NGinx   NGinx
  |      |
  |      |
App     App


  HAProxy
  |      |
  |      |
App     App
```